# If $f'$ is integrable on $[a,b]$, what can we say about $f$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, derivatives

Suppose $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb R$ is a differentiable function with $f'\in L^1 [a,b]$, that is, $f$ has a derivative that is integrable on $[a,b]$. What are some properties $f$ must have?

If any are known, some defining properties would be nice, that is, properties $P$ such that $f$ has $P$ if and only if $f'$ is integrable on $[a,b]$.

One thing we can say is that $f$ must be Lipschitz-continuous. This shouldn't be the best we can do: Lipschitz-continuity follows from the boundedness of $f'$, but we know from [Darboux's theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem_(analysis)) that $f'$ also has the intermediate value property, a very restrictive property. I'm not sure how we could leverage this to get some insight into the nature of $f$. Any ideas?

Comment: Isn’t $f$ then going to be absolutely continuous?

Comment: @AlannRosas After a quick Google search, I found that Lipschitz continuity is stronger than absolute continuity. Someone call me out if I'm wrong, but I think if a function is continuous and the absolute value of its derivative is bounded, then that function is Lipschitz continuous. (BTW, I graduated from the same university as you.)

Comment: If $f = x^{1/3}$, and if you define $f'(0):= 0$, then is $f'$ Lipschitz on $[0,1]$? If you say $f: [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb R$ is differentiable, then we usually imply that it is differentiable on $(a,b)$, so in my opinion it is not proper to assume how $f'$ behaves on the boundary of $(a,b)$.

Comment: The function need not be Lipschitz. Integrability of the derivative does not imply that the derivative is bounded.

Comment: @PhoemueX: I was about to write the same. I just wonder what a counterexample would be. Something like $f(x) = \sqrt x$ does not work because $f$ is assumed to be differentiable *everywhere.*

Comment: @Martin: A monotone $f$ won't work (I think). But something along the lines of $x^\alpha \sin(1/x)$ (with a suitable $\alpha >0$) probably will.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb R$ is differentiable *everywhere* then $f'\in L^1 [a,b]$ if and only if $f$ is absolutely continuous.

This follows from the [equivalent definitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_continuity#Equivalent_definitions) of absolute continuity and the following

> **Theorem** Let $f: [a,b] \rightarrow \bf R$ be an *everywhere* differentiable function whose derivative is Lebesgue integrable. Then
> $$\int_a^b f'(x) \, dx = f(b) - f(a).$$

which is [Theorem 7.21](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZUW25.jpg) in Rudin's Real and Complex Analysis, see also [Proofs of the second fundamental theorem of calculus](https://mathoverflow.net/q/260040/116247) on Math Overflow.

If $f$ is absolutely continuous then $f'$ is integrable on $[a, b]$. Conversely, if $f'$ is integrable, then
$$
 f(x) = f(a) + \int_a^x f'(t) \, dt
$$
according to Rudin's theorem, and that implies that $f$ is absolutely continuous.

Comment: The 3rd edition of the mentioned book doesn't have any theorem 8.21. This is actually theorem 7.21. Also I am not sure why the lower limit of integration is 0 rather than $a$.

Comment: @SuzuHirose: The lower limit was a typo. I have removed the theorem number to avoid confusion. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: It is theorem 7.21. https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZUW25.jpg

Comment: @SuzuHirose: Great, thanks again!